# Adding data dynamically to a asp literal control inside a grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to add data to a literal which place inside a gridview. Currently code look like this

```
protected void GvListingRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
       var query = DisplayAllData();
       Literal info = (Literal)e.Row.FindControl("ltritemInfo");

       if(query != null)
       {
           foreach (var listing in query)
           {
               var list = DisplayListById(listing.id);
               info.Text = "<h3>" + list.title + "</h3>";
               info.Text += "<h4>" + list.description + "</h4>";
           }
       }
}
```

This will generate an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

If anyone has an idea about this it will be great help

Thanks

Comment: When you debug your code, where does it break? In which line your code breaks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure you're only operating on the data rows, and not the header, footer, separator, pager, etc. The enum for this is [`DataControlRowtype`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolrowtype.aspx). This is why your `info` object/reference is null, as it operates on the header first.

- Check that the `e.Row.RowType` is of type `DataRow`.
- For safety, also check that your `info` is not null.

```
protected void GvListingRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {        
       var query = DisplayAllData();
       Literal info = (Literal)e.Row.FindControl("ltritemInfo");

       if(query != null && info !=null) 
       {
           foreach (var listing in query)
           {
                var list = DisplayListById(listing.id);
                info.Text = string.Format("<h3>{0}</h3><h4>{1}</h4>",
                               list.title, list.description);    
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: when i run the code with a bereak point it shows me that it picking up the correct value for the   info.Text = "<h3>" + list.title + "</h3>"; but it generates that error

Comment: **Which exact line from the code in this answer** throws an error? Have you set a breakpoint within?